# Cannot post /feedback.php

Tags: php, html, xampp

My contact form doesn't work, I get the error "Cannot POST /feedback.php"
Here is the html-file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Форма обратной связи</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <form class="form" action="feedback.php" method="POST">
        <h3 class="form__title">Форма обратной связи</h3>
        <div class="form__field">
          <label class="form__label form__label_required" for="last_name">
            Фамилия
          </label>
          <input class="form__input" id="last_name" name="last_name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form__field">
          <label class="form__label form__label_required" for="first_name">
            Имя
          </label>
          <input
            class="form__input"
            id="first_name"
            name="first_name"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form__field">
          <label class="form__label form__label_required" for="email">
            Электронная почта
          </label>
          <input
            class="form__input"
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form__field">
          <label class="form__label form__label_required" for="quality">
            Оцените качество обслуживания
          </label>
          <div class="form__radio-buttons">
            <div class="form__radio-container">
              <input
                class="form__radio"
                type="radio"
                id="quality-1"
                name="quality"
                value="1"
                required
              />
              <label for="quality-1">1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__radio-container">
              <input
                class="form__radio"
                type="radio"
                id="quality-2"
                name="quality"
                value="2"
                required
              />
              <label for="quality-2">2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__radio-container">
              <input
                class="form__radio"
                type="radio"
                id="quality-3"
                name="quality"
                value="3"
                required
              />
              <label for="quality-3">3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__radio-container">
              <input
                class="form__radio"
                type="radio"
                id="quality-4"
                name="quality"
                value="4"
                required
              />
              <label for="quality-4">4</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__radio-container">
              <input
                class="form__radio"
                type="radio"
                id="quality-5"
                name="quality"
                value="5"
                required
              />
              <label for="quality-5">5</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__field">
          <label class="form__label" for="like">
            Выберите, что вам больше всего понравилось
          </label>
          <div class="form__checkbox-container">
            <input
              class="form__checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="like-service-speed"
              name="like-service-speed"
            />
            <label for="like-service-speed">Скорость обслуживания</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form__checkbox-container">
            <input
              class="form__checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="like-interface"
              name="like-interface"
            />
            <label for="like-interface">Понятный и простой интерфейс</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form__checkbox-container">
            <input
              class="form__checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="like-assortment"
              name="like-assortment"
            />
            <label for="like-assortment">Большой выбор товаров</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__field">
          <label class="form__label" for="comment"> Комментарий </label>
          <textarea
            class="form__textarea"
            id="comment"
            name="comment"
            maxlength="255"
          ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form__comment">
          Поля, помеченные <label class="form__label_required"></label>,
          являются обязательными
        </div>
        <button class="form__button" type="submit">Отправить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the feedback.php:

```
<?php

require 'database.php';

function get_optional_param($key)
{
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
}

print_r($_POST);

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$quality = intval($_POST["quality"]);
$like_service_speed = get_optional_param("like-service-speed") == "on";
$like_interface = get_optional_param("like-interface") == "on";
$like_assortment = get_optional_param("like-assortment") == "on";
$comment = get_optional_param("comment");

create_feedback(
    $mysqli,
    $first_name,
    $last_name,
    $email,
    $quality,
    $like_service_speed,
    $like_interface,
    $like_assortment,
    $comment
);

header("Location: feedback-success.html");
?>
```

database.php for the full picture:

```
<?php

function create_feedback_table($mysqli)
{
    $sql = "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_feedback (
            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            quality INT NOT NULL CHECK(quality BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
            like_service_speed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            like_interface BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            like_assortment BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            comment VARCHAR(255)
        )
    ";
    if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
        die("Error creating table: " . $mysqli->error);
    }
}

function create_feedback(
    $mysqli,
    $first_name,
    $last_name,
    $email,
    $quality,
    $like_service_speed = false,
    $like_interface = false,
    $like_assortment = false,
    $comment = null
) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
        "
        INSERT INTO user_feedback (
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            quality,
            like_service_speed,
            like_interface,
            like_assortment,
            comment
        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    "
    );
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "sssdddds",
        $first_name,
        $last_name,
        $email,
        $quality,
        $like_service_speed,
        $like_interface,
        $like_assortment,
        $comment
    );
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die("Error insert user: " . $mysqli->error);
    }
    return $stmt->insert_id;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "store");

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

create_feedback_table($mysqli);
?>
```

I use xampp and files are in the same template xampp/htdocs/feedback
Apache and MySql are working

I can't handle this problem for 2 days, please, give me a hand

Comment: In your browser's development tools, on the Network tab, what is the response from the server when posting the form?  For example, if the server returns an HTTP 500 status code then that means an error occurred on the server, in which case you'd need to check the PHP error logs and generally debug the server-side code to find the underlying problem.

Comment: Here's the log
POST http://localhost:3002/feedback.php 404 (Not Found)
feedback.php:7 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ws://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Bed9qzUU2IVkAAxp73fh88GAnMchALEvifOr4XcPQ/4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
@David

Comment: A 404 error means the server couldn't find the resource requested.  What is the URL of the page in the browser, and what are the paths of the files involved?

Comment: _"I get the error `Cannot POST /feedback.php`"_ - what, _literally_? Just that?

Comment: URL **http://localhost:3000/** I use also gulp and browserSync for updating the page consistantely. Folder path is C:\xampp\htdocs\feedback, all the files are in it

Comment: Yes, exatcly it @CBroe

Comment: _"URL localhost:3000"_ - what you say you quoted from the log (_which_ one, btw.?), was `POST localhost:3002/feedback.php 404 (Not Found)` - so which base URL is it actually now?

Comment: Sorry, it is 3000, and no 404 error in the log, only **Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:**

Comment: _"And the feedback.php:"_ - that doesn't look like it would produce _any_ output. And yet, you quoted an error `feedback.php:7 Refused to execute inline script because ...` from the browser console, that also doesn't make sense - _what_ inline script would that be? _"Sorry, it is 3000, and no 404 error in the log"_ - then what was the `POST localhost:3002/feedback.php 404 (Not Found)`, which you quoted earlier?

Comment: _POST localhost:3002/feedback.php 404 (Not Found)_ was from different terminal, nevermind

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by editing settings of Apache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).